# CORS rejects GET

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-web-api, axios, cors

I can login on my site and I get token from API by POST.
Now I try by using GET some data from API but it returns CORS error or 401. I use Vue.js on client site and ASP.NET Freamwork 4.6 as API.
On Postman API work.

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvYSu.png)

A bit of my Vue.js code:

```
GetUsers: function(Page = 1){
        const URI = "http://localhost:5000/api/user?Page="+Page;
        var optionsAxios = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("user-token"),
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }
        //var querystring = require('querystring');
        axios.get(URI, optionsAxios).then((result) =>{
                console.log(result.results)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    },
```

In Web.config in API I added

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:8080" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Now it returns
**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource**

If I use

```
const URI = "http://localhost:5000/api/user
```

and GET

```
        var querystring = require('querystring');
        axios.get(URI,
            querystring.stringify({
                page: Page
            }),
            optionsAxios).then((result) =>{
                console.log(result.results)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
```

It will return
**Error: Request failed with status code 401**

**EDIT**

I tried add in **Web.config**

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:8080" /> <-- This one I had before
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, Pragma, Cache-Control, Authorization " />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Nothing changed no matter in what combination.

Next one I tried was

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:8080", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

in **WebApiConfig.cs**
In this one I can't even Login on site.

Google Chrome shows me:
**has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.**

Firefox shows:
**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/api/user?Page=5. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed)**

And

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/api/user?Page=5. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).**

**EDIT2**

I fixed that maybe in not the best way but it works. I needed combine all methods I found in one.

In **Web.config**

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:8080" />-->
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, Pragma, Cache-Control, Authorization " />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I commented Allow Origin.
Added in **WebApiConfig.cs**

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:8080", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

and in Global.asax/Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Preflight request comes with HttpMethod OPTIONS
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
            // The following line solves the error message
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            // If any http headers are shown in preflight error in browser console add them below
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Pragma, Cache-Control, Authorization ");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

And after that all it is fixed.
For sure there is too much code.

Comment: What URL is the application downloaded from?

Comment: It is not downloaded

Comment: maybe  this error occurred because of your token @DonQnei

Comment: I tried this token in Postman and it worked.

Comment: *It is not downloaded* - how did it get into the browser? Even if a browser downloads an app from a web server running on the localhost, it is still downloading the app..

Comment: you need to include CORS from Nuget package manager. then include CORS attribute on controller or action level to allow CORS. you can also apply from global.asax

Comment: Ahh ok.. I thought you say about my code... App was written by person in company. I just compile this in VS (IIS). API run on localhost:5000 and front on localhost:8080. In API address to user controller is GET: api/user. Vue code from above work on http://localhost:8080/#/Users. If this aren't URL you ask about idk about what you ask. I don't use any other.

Comment: try on axios cors: 'no-cors'

Comment: Note that postman works because it doesn't care about CORS/it doesn't make preflight requests; it just hits the API you ask it to. You can use Postman to do an OPTIONS like a browser would, but that screenshot you've put there (what little of it we can see) is probably just banging the relevant API directly - the browser isn't getting that far (it isn't hitting your API, it's deciding not to call it based on the OPTIONS response it's getting)

Comment: *And after that all it is fixed* - which is in essence the original problem my answer responded on, its just that the fiddling you did to get it to work eventually involved setting response headers in global.asax directly, probably because your IIS doesn't actually have a CORS module installed, so nothing is reading the config settings you were making/the headers weren't being added to OPTIONS requests because your IIS isn't CORS capable. By literally directly setting custom headers on the response (like the CORS module would) you've managed to get your browser to receive the headers it wants

Comment: Ok thanks, I will check this out later. Now I need create views. For now I'm fine with this how it works, because I can't test my views and how they create tables etc. if I don't get data from API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When an app interacts with a back end and a CORS policy applies, the browser will first contact the back end and say "this app I'm running wants something from an URL you deal with; you didn't serve the app up, so tell me what characteristics you allow for apps asking for urls like that" - the back end gives the list of characteristics, and then the browser looks to see if the app it's running, that it downloaded from place X, meets the criteria.

If it doesn't, the app experiences a refusal without getting any further - that is to say, that if the browser says to the server `OPTIONS /someurl` and gets back a response that doesn't include any CORS headers, or includes something that doesn't match the request being made, then the *browser( will issue the 401 to your app; it's nothing to do with the server - the server never even knew you were trying to `GET /someurl` - all it saw was an `OPTIONS /someurl` issued by the browser first, and if no CORS headers are included with its response to the OPTIONS, the browser won't even try to do the `GET` on behalf of your app

The host and port number the app is hosted at is what must be allowed in the CORS config, so if your app is downloaded from http://xyz:1234 and during its operations it will make requests to an API at https://abc:9876, then the config of that API must have `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://xyz:1234" />` in its config.

There are other things that CORS can apply to too, such as the HTTP method that the app is attempting to use to access the back end: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods

*Edit: Note that IIS doesn't necessarily support putting CORS in the web.config out of the box - you have to have [the CORS module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module) installed - without it, you can write whatever CORS stuff you like in the config file and IIS will just ignore it, because it doesn't know to look for it or how to take any action on it if it finds it*

Comment: I have... Even I posted part of API Web.config code above with this line. And I can use POST and CORS don't reject this, but I can't use GET.

Comment: Check then that your CORS policy allows GET as well as POST e.g. putting `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *` into your CORS config